# Using a jar in a Java project?

Tags: java, linux, command-line, jar

I'm trying to use the public methods/classed from a project provided as a jar file (called Hello.jar for instance) wrapped in a package called hello.

```
package hello;

public class Hello
{

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    coucou();
 }

 public static void coucou()
 {
   System.out.println("Hello there");
 }

}
```

In a separate project called Tool, I want to be able to call the method `Hello.coucou()` so I wrote something like this:

```
import hello.*;

public class Tool
{

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   System.out.println("main program running");
   Hello.coucou();

 }

}
```

and I compiled Tool.java with the following command (under linux):

```
$ javac Tool.java -classpath .:./extern/:
```

where Hello.jar is located in the folder `./extern`

This seems to compile fine but when I launch it (i.e. java Tool), I get this:

```
main program running
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello/Hello
    at Tool.main(Tool.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello.Hello
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:336)
    ... 1 more
```

I am new to Java (C/C++ background) and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Any ideas?

Cheers
David

---

**Edit:** I tried adding Hello.jar to the classpath on the command line, but I still get the same error:

```
$ javac Tool.java -classpath .:./extern/Hello.jar:
$ java Tool -classpath .:./extern/Hello.jar:
main program running
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello/Hello
    at Tool.main(Tool.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello.Hello
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:336)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: I'd expect semi-colons rather than colons separating the class paths.

Comment: Windows: semi-colons Linux: colons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the trick was in the order of the arguments in the command line:

Is the -cp (or -classpath) is set last, then it doesn't work

```
java Tool -cp .:extern/Hello.jar
```

It has to be first like:

```
java -cp .:extern/Hello.jar Tool
```

!!!

Comment: Yes. Otherwise the "-cp whatever" is passed to main() as the args array. You need to keep in mind the difference between args to the java runtime and the args to your program.

Answer (score 4):

You need the Hello.jar on the classpath when you run as well as when you compile.

Answer (score 1):

When you run Java you must add the jar file too (adding the directory path only does not work).

See [classpath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) information.

It should be something like this:

```
java -classpath /java/MyClasses/myclasses.jar utility.myapp.Cool
```

Comment: Actually the semi-colon mess things up completely and it should really be a colon. The trick to the problem was to have the -classpath option first, i.e. before Tool.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I somehow ignored the Linux part of the question, but updated the answer to reflect this when I realised.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses dynamic late binding, so putting the JAR in the classpath during compilation is only necessary to ensure that your code is using the classes from it correctly, but it does not actually embed them into your code as the linker would in C/C++. Thus, you need to set the classpath also when executing the code.

However, this:

```
$ javac Tool.java -classpath .:./extern/:
```

should not work either, since JARs need to be put into the classpath directly, not just the directory they live in:

```
$ javac Tool.java -classpath .:./extern/Hello.jar
```

Finally, you are placing your code in the default nameless package. This is OK for fooling around, but will cause problems in the long run (for one thing, you cannot import classes FROM the default package anywhere else).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Hello.jar file in the classpath when you launch it too.

Answer (score 0):

java -cp xxx.jar hello where xxx is the jar you want to have in your classpath, if you want multiple jars then separate them using ;

karl