# creating our own jar and using it in another project

Tags: java, jar

I want to create our own jar which has some simple methods like a print method.

I created the jar of that java project and imported it into an other project I am building path also.

The problem is that I am able to create the object of the classes which reside in the jar but I am unable to call the methods of that class.
 i am using eclipse 3.4 (Eclipse Ganymede (3.4))version

Comment: Do you get compile or run-time errors? Please post them.

Comment: May this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970940/using-a-jar-in-a-java-project

Comment: where is the code? you said you could create object but could not call method? was that method public?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like if you are successfully building the JAR that you are not including it in the classpath when you compile / run your application.  You can do that if you are compiling/running from the command line with the `-cp` or `-classpath` option.  Both perform the same function.

To compile:

```
javac -cp .:PathToMyJar/MyJar.jar MyMainClass.java
```

To Run:

```
java -cp .:PathToMyJar/MyJar.jar MyMainClass
```

The above commands will look in the current directory ('.') and in the MyJar.jar file specified. On Windows you will separate the items in the classpath with a semicolon and on Linux/Unix/OS X you will use a colon.

If you are using an IDE you will need to somehow add the JAR file to the classpath for your project. How to do that is IDE specific.