# Export class to jar and use in another/same project

Tags: java, jar

I just developed an application in java and I need to handover the code partially.
So, what is I want to achieve is

I've a class `manageTask.Java` at  `com.project.users.manageTask` and As I need to handover the source code, excluding one class file, I want to create a jar file for that class and use with same project instead of that `manageTask.Java`

Somebody Please guide

Edit: 
IDE: Eclipse
And there are a couple of external dependent jar for `manageTask.Java`

Comment: generate build.xml in eclipse. Exclude the only source file that you dont want to ship. and use ant to build product

Comment: Create a project, put the class into it, compile it and add the resulting jar as a dependency. Share the jar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating our own jar and using it in another project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315716/creating-our-own-jar-and-using-it-in-another-project)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your class name should be `ManageTask.Java` and not `manageTask.Java`.

To export jar, right click your project in eclipse, select Export int he popup menu and then choose jar int he wizard that opens. After that you should be able to find what you need.